# How can i put this code in a user defined method with "public static double processType(String inType, int inMax, boolean dropOne)"

Tags: java, arrays, string, user-defined-functions

This program works perfect. I wanna know how do I put this methods into user defined method which will read quiz labs prog and exams. `public static double processType(String inType, int inMax, boolean dropOne` Use this and how do I read in the Quiz, Lab , prog as a string intype

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    /*
     * Calculate the Grade for a class
     * does peter
     */
    public class grade
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int weightQuiz,
            weightLabs,
            weightProg,
            weightExam,
            totalQuizScore,
            totalLabScore,
            totalProgScore,
            totalExamScore;

            double maxQuiz,
            maxQuizVal,
            minQuizVal,
            minQuiz,
            maxLab,
            maxLabVal,
            minLab,
            minLabVal,
            maxProg,
            maxProgVal,
            minProg,
            minProgVal,
            maxExam,
            maxExamVal,
            minExam,
            minExamVal,
            quizScore,
            labScore,
            progScore,
            examScore;

            double finalGradeAvg;
            final int HUNDRED = 100;
            final double ROUNDING = 100;
            final double SINGLE = 1;
            final double AGRADE = 92;
            final double AMINUS = 90;
            final double BPLUS = 88;
            final double BGRADE = 82;
            final double BMINUS = 80;
            final double CPLUS = 78;
            final double CGRADE = 72;        
            final double CMINUS = 70;
            final double DPLUS = 68;
            final double DGRADE = 62;
            final double DMINUS = 56;
            final double FGRADE = 55 ;

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter weights (quizzes, labs, programs, exams): ");        
            weightQuiz = input.nextInt();
            weightLabs = input.nextInt();
            weightProg = input.nextInt();
            weightExam = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter maximum scores (quizzes, labs, programs, exams): ");
            maxQuiz = input.nextDouble();
            maxLab= input.nextDouble();
            maxProg = input.nextDouble();
            maxExam = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("\nHow many QUIZ scores? ");
            totalQuizScore = input.nextInt();   
            System.out.print("Enter QUIZ scores: ");
            maxQuizVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            minQuizVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            quizScore = 0;
            double quizArr = 0;

            for (int i = 0 ; i < totalQuizScore ; i ++ )   
            {
                quizScore = input.nextDouble(); 
                if ( quizScore > maxQuizVal )
                    maxQuizVal = quizScore;
                if(quizScore < minQuizVal )
                    minQuizVal = quizScore;
                quizArr += quizScore; 
            }      
            double rawAverageQuiz = 0;
            double rawAvgQuiz;
            double avgQuiz;
            double averageQuiz;
            double adjAverageQuiz;
            double adjAvgQuiz;   
            double numQuiz;
            double denomQuiz;
            double adAvgQuiz; 
            double finalAdjQuiz;
            avgQuiz = (quizArr / maxQuiz);
            averageQuiz = avgQuiz / totalQuizScore;
            adAvgQuiz = (int) ( averageQuiz * HUNDRED ) / ROUNDING;

            numQuiz = ((quizArr - minQuizVal) / maxQuiz);
            denomQuiz = (totalQuizScore - SINGLE);
            adjAverageQuiz = (numQuiz / denomQuiz);
            adjAvgQuiz = (int) (adjAverageQuiz * HUNDRED) / ROUNDING;

            System.out.println("\nQUIZ summary ");
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("        How many: "+ totalQuizScore);
            System.out.println("             Min: "+ minQuizVal);
            System.out.println("             Max: "+ maxQuizVal);
            System.out.println("     Raw average: "+ adAvgQuiz);
            System.out.println("Adjusted average: "+ adjAvgQuiz);

            System.out.print("\nHow many LAB scores? ");
            totalLabScore = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter LAB scores: ");       
            maxLabVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            minLabVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            labScore = 1;
            double labArr = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < totalLabScore; i++)   
            {  
                labScore = input.nextDouble();
                if (labScore > maxLabVal )
                    maxLabVal = labScore;
                if(labScore < minLabVal)
                    minLabVal = labScore;
                labArr += labScore; 
            }
            double rawAverageLab = 0;
            double avgLab;
            double averageLab;
            double rawAvgLab;
            double adjAverageLab;
            double adjAvgLab;
            double numLab;
            double denomLab;
            double adAvgLab = 0;

            avgLab = (labArr / maxLab);
            averageLab  = avgLab  / totalLabScore;
            adAvgLab = (int) (averageLab  * HUNDRED ) / ROUNDING; 
            numLab = ((labArr - minLabVal) / maxLab);
            denomLab = (totalLabScore - SINGLE);
            adjAverageLab = (numLab/denomLab);
            adjAvgLab = (int) (adjAverageLab * HUNDRED) / ROUNDING; 

            System.out.println("\nLAB summary ");
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("        How many: " + totalLabScore);
            System.out.println("             Min: " + minLabVal);
            System.out.println("             Max: " + maxLabVal);
            System.out.println("     Raw average: " + adAvgLab);
            System.out.println("Adjusted average: " + adjAvgLab);

            System.out.print("\nHow many PROGRAM scores? ");
            totalProgScore = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter PROGRAM scores: ");
            maxProgVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            minProgVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;        
            progScore = 1;
            double progArr = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < totalProgScore ; i++)
            {  
                progScore = input.nextDouble();
                if (progScore > maxProgVal )
                    maxProgVal = progScore;
                if(progScore < minProgVal)
                    minProgVal = progScore;
                progArr += progScore;
            }
            double rawAverageProg = 0;
            double avgProg;
            double averageProg;
            double rawAvgProg;
            double adjAverageProg;
            double adjAvgProg;
            double numProg;
            double denomProg;

            avgProg = (progArr / maxProg);
            averageProg = avgProg / totalProgScore;
            rawAvgProg = (int) (averageProg  * HUNDRED) / ROUNDING;       
            System.out.println("\nProgram summary ");
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("        How many: "+ totalProgScore);
            System.out.println("             Min: "+ minProgVal);
            System.out.println("             Max: "+ maxProgVal);
            System.out.println("     Raw average: "+ rawAvgProg);

            System.out.print("\nHow many EXAM scores? ");
            totalExamScore = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter EXAM scores: ");       
            maxExamVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            minExamVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            examScore = 1;
            double examArr = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < totalExamScore; i++)       
            {  
                examScore = input.nextDouble();
                if (examScore > maxExamVal )
                    maxExamVal = examScore;
                if(examScore < minExamVal )
                    minExamVal = examScore;
                examArr += examScore;
            }

            double rawAverageExam = 0;
            double rawAvgExam;
            double avgExam;
            double averageExam;
            double adjAverageExam;
            double adjAvgExam;
            double numExam;
            double denomExam;

            avgExam = (examArr / maxExam);
            averageExam = avgExam / totalExamScore;
            rawAvgExam = (int) ( averageExam * HUNDRED) / ROUNDING;
            System.out.println("\nEXAM summary ");
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("        How many: "+ totalExamScore);
            System.out.println("             Min: "+ minExamVal);
            System.out.println("             Max: "+ maxExamVal);
            System.out.println("     Raw average: "+ rawAvgExam);

            System.out.println("\nFINAL summary");
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");            
            finalGradeAvg = ((adjAvgQuiz * weightQuiz ) + (adjAvgLab * weightLabs) + (rawAvgProg * weightProg) + (rawAvgExam * weightExam));
            double adjFinalGradeAvg = (int) ((finalGradeAvg / HUNDRED) * HUNDRED) / ROUNDING;
            System.out.println("Final grade adjusted average: " + adjFinalGradeAvg);

            if (finalGradeAvg >= AGRADE )
                System.out.println(" Final grade adjusted letter: A");
            else if (finalGradeAvg  >= AMINUS) 
                System.out.println(" Final grade adjusted letter: A-");
            else if (finalGradeAvg  >= BPLUS) 
                System.out.println(" Final grade adjusted letter: B+");
            else if (finalGradeAvg  >= BGRADE) 
                System.out.println(" Final grade adjusted letter: B+");
            else if (finalGradeAvg  >= BMINUS) 
                System.out.println(" Final grade adjusted letter: B-");
            else if (finalGradeAvg  >= CPLUS) 
                System.out.println(" Final grade adjusted letter: C+");
            else if (finalGradeAvg  >= CGRADE) 
                System.out.println(" Final grade adjusted letter: C");
            else if (finalGradeAvg  >= CMINUS) 
                System.out.println(" Final grade adjusted letter: C");
            else if (finalGradeAvg  >= DPLUS)
                System.out.println(" Final grade adjusted letter: D+");
            else if (finalGradeAvg  >= DGRADE)
                System.out.println(" Final grade adjusted letter: D");
            else if (finalGradeAvg  >= DMINUS)
                System.out.println(" Final grade adjusted letter: D-");
            else if (finalGradeAvg  <= FGRADE)
                System.out.println(" Final grade adjusted letter: F");        
            System.out.println("\nDONE. Normal termination.");

        }
    }
```

Comment: think of methods as a way of boxing your program into smaller chunks. your program is extremely over complicated but it seems you are trying to do same things three times (this could you where method can be useful)

Comment: Yea so my question is , will I be putting in user defined codes for all the four parts(quiz, lab, program and exam) coz that is then gonna be the same amount of coding. I will be dropping the least score of the quiz and lab and then calculate the average. So how is that possible, totally confused :(  @nafas please Help